# Не переведено описание причины закрытия про объективный ответ

Tags: дефект, локализация, причины-закрытия, мобильное-приложение

Речь о мобильном приложении.
Все остальные уже починили, а эту еще нет.

[image: невозможно дать объективный ответ]

Comment: Хм, у меня всё норм.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica может от репы зависит. Текст всё же другой. Про удаление ничего не сказано в частности.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica Хм. На сайте норм, а в мобильном приложении нет.